# How to parse a string containing RDF n-triples?

Tags: java, parsing, rdf

I have a file which reads rdf n-triples format. But, I am not allowed to use third party API's (like jena etc... It's a different debate).

But basically, I can get two kinds of string:

```
<foo 1> <bar 1> <foo bar> .
<foo 2> <bar 2> foobar .
```

So, I want to write a class:

```
void ParseTriples(String s){
   setObject(<foo> part)
   setPredicate(<bar part>)
   setObject(<foobar> or foobar)

}
```

What I have is a hack..

```
public void setNTriples(String text){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
        //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([^>]*)>\\s+[<]?([^>]*)[>]?");
        //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<[a-zA-Z.\\d\\s]+>|\\w+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        int count = 0;
        int end = 0;
        int totalLength = text.length();
        while(matcher.find()) {
            if (count == 0){
                //System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                setSubject(new Text(matcher.group(1)));
                //length += getSubject().toString().length();
                //System.out.println(length);
                count +=1;
            }
            else if (count == 1){


                setPredicate(new Text(matcher.group(1)));
                count +=1;

                end = matcher.end();
            }
            else if (count == 2){
                //System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                setObject(new Text(matcher.group(1)));
                count +=1;
                //System.out.println(text.substring(length+5, totalLength));
            }

        }
        //System.out.println(count);
        // ugly hack
        if (count == 2){
            setObject(new Text(text.substring(end+1,totalLength-2)));
        }


    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just use a regular expression match for `^<([^>]+)>\s+<([^>]+)>\s+<?([^>]+)>?$` instead? http://www.debuggex.com/r/sSJBdZuSTtL-4JpB

Comment: So, you're trying to write an rdf parser, and for some reason or another, you can't just use some third-party parser?

Comment: @TedPercival: basically I want to identify Subject, Object and Predicate part?

Comment: @DennisMeng: yepp..like i said.. its a different debate.. i already debated this internally but to no avail..

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to make sure that bit was clear before any "why aren't you using rdf parser, noob?" people show up.

Comment: "How do i fix this.." - how to fix what ? you code works with both scenarios...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Whats an equivalent java regex : I get this error for that pattern Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: for java, use double \\ for every \ in the pattern

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: There is a "." in the end as well .. can you please update your regex to include that

Comment: I can tell you how to update it. $ is the end of the line, so add \s+\. (corrected for slashes) in front of that for "one or more whitespace characters and then a full stop"

Comment: I rolled back the last edit, because it deleted all of the meaningful code, which removed all the context for the comments as well as the accepted solution (which said, e.g., "Not that I find your solution too ugly…" and which made no sense when the question didn't show an attempted solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not that I find your solution too ugly, but another option is

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:<([^>]+)>\s*){2}<?([^>]+)>?$");  
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
       return new Triple(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
    } else{
       // error handling code
    }
```

Edit: Not compiled (no JRE at hand) but the syntax explains a non-captured group `?:` that gets repeated 2 times `{2}` (in case some refinement is needed); at the end is the option of getting the last group inside brackets or without.

Comment: note: this will fail on the second case the OP lists, which has no angle brackets in the third term.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans yes I missed the difference between the two lines, I hope I did not miss something else now. Thank you.

Comment: @SJuan76: There is a dot in the end as well :)